# How to print a void method from main method

Tags: java, abstract-class, static

Okay so I have three class

```
abstract class Shape  
{  
int width, height;  
String color;

public void draw()    
{      
}
    } // end Shape class
```

``

```
class Rectangle extends Shape
   {
Rectangle(int w, int h, String color)
{
    width = w;
    height = h;
    this.color = new String(color);
}

public void draw()
{
    System.out.println("I am a " + color + " Rectangle " + width + " wide and " + height + " high.");
}
   }// end Rectangle class
```

``

```
 class Circle extends Shape
   {
  Circle (int r, String color)
   {
    width = 2*r;
    height = 2*r;
    this.color = new String(color);   
}
public void draw()
{
    System.out.println("I am a " + color + " Circle with radius " + width + ".");
}
    } // end Circle class
```

`` What I am trying to do is create a new class to produce the following outputs: 
I am a blue Rectangle 20 wide and 10 high.
I am a red Circle with radius 30.
I am a green Rectangle 25 wide and 25 high 
But I am having a problem calling the method draw();

```
 This is the main class:
 public class Caller
  {
   public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
Caller call= new Caller();
Shape[] myShape = new Shape[3];

   myShape[0] = new Rectangle(20,10,"blue");
   myShape[1] = new Circle(30, "red");
   myShape[2] = new Rectangle(25,25, "green");
   for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
     {
System.out.println();
     }
    call.draw(Rectangle);
    call.draw(Circle);
   } 
   }
```

Comment: regarding, `"But I am having a problem calling the method draw();"` -- What problem are you having? You will want to ask as *specific* a question as possible if we're to be able to help you well.

Comment: maybe it helps if you figure out which member variables are private, protected or public. Note that you don't specify this in your code and afaik Java uses protected as default.

Comment: Whould be nice if you keep a eye to your code indenting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `for` loop you need to call the `draw` method for the specific `Shape` that you're on and you don't need to call `System.out.println()` unless you want another blank line.

```
for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
{
    myShape[i].draw();
}
```

Remove the lines like `call.draw`.  You don't use `call` to call a method.  In fact you don't even need an instance of your `Caller` object.  Just call the `draw` method on the `Shape` objects you already have.

As in jlordo's answer, there is no need for the `Shape` class to be abstract if it has no methods.  So you can either make the `draw` method `abstract`, or you can remove `abstract` from the `Shape` class.

Answer (score 2):

Your code formatting is horrible, so this is just a guess. I think you should change

```
for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
     {
System.out.println();
     }
    call.draw(Rectangle);
    call.draw(Circle);
```

to

```
for (int i=0; i < myShape.length; i++) {
    myShape[i].draw();
}
```

Also, in the `Shape` class change

```
public void draw()
{
}
```

to

```
public abstract void draw();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I know my code isn't that professional but I'm new at this. Thanks jlordo and rgettman. You guys were most helpful

Answer (score 1):

Your draw() method is defined on your Shape classes, not on your Caller class.

myShape[0].draw() to print out the rectangle for example.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

1) The draw() method in the abstract class should be made abstract. Or, you could implement it as "partial" like in the solution I post further down, then without the abstract keyword at the Shape class:

2) new String("color") is not needed. Strings are immutable, so you can just write as below.

3) you miss specifying if your class members are private or public or protected. It is always a good idea to think about visibility of variables.

4) You try to print the diameter not the radius

5) You try to call a method on the class and not on the instance

Here is my suggestion (untested... there might be more issues that i did not see):

```
class Shape  
{  
  protected int width, height;  
  protected String color;

  public void draw()    
  {      
    System.out.print("I am a " + color");
  }
} // end Shape class

class Rectangle extends Shape
{
  Rectangle(int w, int h, String color)
  {
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
    this.color = color;
  }

  public void draw()
  {
    super();
    System.out.print(" Rectangle " + width + " wide and " + height + " high.\n");
  }
}// end Rectangle class

class Circle extends Shape
{
  Circle (int r, String color)
  {
    this.width = 2*r;
    this.height = 2*r;
    this.color = new String(color);   
  }
  public void draw()
  {
    super();
    System.out.print(" Circle with radius " + (width/2) + ".\n");
  }
} // end Circle class
```

later in the main method you need to do something like:

```
Shape[] myShape = new Shape[3];

myShape[0] = new Rectangle(20,10,"blue");
myShape[1] = new Circle(30, "red");
myShape[2] = new Rectangle(25,25, "green");
for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
{
  myShape[i].draw();
}
```